# Rails 3: create a Parent via a child's 'nested form'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parent-child, nested-forms, relationship, nested-attributes

```
class Parent
  has_many :children
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parent
end
```

The form is the usual nested form, but from the Child's perspective:

```
=nested_form_for @child do |f|
  =f.fields_for :parent
  …
```

I'd like to let users choose from a select menu with Parents names. And additionally enable them to create a new Parent record if needed.
So how to create a *Parent* from the child's form if it doesn't yet exist?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to pop up the parent create form in a window/layer when the users select 'create new' from the select menu and then have the return result re-render the nested_form with the new list of parents with the newly added parent already selected.

The same principles apply without javascript, though you probably need a 'Add new parent' button that goes to the new parent form and then redirects back to the child form on creation with the new parent already selected.